# Best way to store images in sql server on a network server

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing an application that needs to store large images
and about 100 image a day 
about 3 people work on the same application DB (desktop application connected to same db)

any one of theme can view , edit, delete other work 
which means all of theme can access certain image at once

now the question is what is the best way to store images this big 
(currently I'm storing the images in a table but i know this eventually will suck)

I'm using sql server 2008

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store tiff images in SQL Server or file system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234551/store-tiff-images-in-sql-server-or-file-system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the new in v2008 [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) data type to store your images. This is a hybrid approach that means the data can be queried from SQL, but the data itself is stored  in the filesystem rather than in the database.